# I'm using moodle with WSDL and Nusoap but I cannot connect because I have errors in my code

Tags: php, wsdl, moodle, soapserver

#### obtenerDatosCentro.php code

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

// incluimos los datos necesarios para establecer conexion con la BD
include("conexion.php");

require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$miURL = 'http://localhost/seguimiento';

$endpoint = 'http://localhost/seguimiento/obtenerDatosCentro.php';

$server = new soap_server(URL_WSDL, array('encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1'));


//$server->configureWSDL('Web Service', $miURL,$endpoint);

//$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace=$miURL;

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$consulta = query();

//$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
//$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

$server->register(
                     'mostrar',       // method name
                     array('$cadena' => 'xsd:string'),                     // output parameters
                     'urn:getfile1',      // namespace
                     'urn:getfile1/getFile',    // SOAPAction
                     'rpc',        // style
                     'encoded'       
    );

//$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

class ObtenerDatos {

    function mostrar(){

        $cadena = "Hola";

        return $cadena;
    }

    /*function obtenerDatosCentro() {


        $list = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {


            $list= array('ID_CENTRO' => array('ORIGEN_CENTRO' => $row['ORIGEN_CENTRO'], 'CODIGO_CENTRO' => $row['CODIGO_CENTRO']), 'NOMBRE_CENTRO'=>$row['NOMBRE_CENTRO'], 'URL_PLATAFORMA'=>$row['URL_PLATAFORMA'],
          'URL_SEGUIMIENTO'=>$row['URL_SEGUIMIENTO'],'TELEFONO'=>$row['TELEFONO'],'EMAIL'=>$row['EMAIL']); ?>


            <center><h1>Mostrar Datos Centro</h1>

          <table border="1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="primera_fila">ID_CENTRO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">ORIGEN_CENTRO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">CODIGO_CENTRO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">NOMBRE_CENTRO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">URL_PLATAFORMA</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">URL_SEGUIMIENTO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">TELEFONO</td>
                <td class="primera_fila">EMAIL</td>

                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 

            <?php while($filas->$list->mysqli_fetch_assoc())?>

                <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>ID_CENTRO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>ORIGEN_CENTRO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>CODIGO_CENTRO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>NOMBRE_CENTRO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>URL_PLATAFORMA ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>URL_SEGUIMIENTO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>TELEFONO ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $filas>EMAIL ?></td>
                </tr>   

            </center>           

    <?php } 

    }*/


}
?>
```

I tried using soap and nusoap. I commented out some lines because I was trying them, but nothing was working at all.

Now I only have the following error.

> You cannot bind to an external WSDL file, and register methods outside of it! Please choose either WSDL or no WSDL.

I think I have to register all the methods I have in obtenerDatosCentro.php, but I don't know what to do.